# ASP MVC doesn't redirect after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I am wondering if its possible to keep the model content after a submit (Post) without a redirection on the same controller.

The scenario: I want the user to press a button that will submit the content to the repository and therefore database and the contents will be available so they can go and edit it straight away - I know i can code a new method but I think this is overkill for what I want?

I have tried returning nothing or null in the ActionResult but the page just goes blank.

```
 ElseIf command = "Save" Then
   Return RedirectToAction("method", "controller", New With {parameters....}    
 ElseIf command = "Apply" Then
//I want the page to remain static so they can edit straight away
   Return Nothing
```

Any advice would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: do you want to redirect the user to edit page after successful save

Comment: Why not do a redirect to the same edit view again ?

Comment: I have a GET request which builds the model up from a set of parameters sent via a different controller so I cant really use the same method unless I change some of the existing code which means I will need to retest everything, though this isnt a headache and wouldnt be a big change I was wondering if there is something I could use to just keep the same model state on the same page without any redirection?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to stay on the same page (and without the page reloading) after you submit the form data? If so, you probably want to submit the form via ajax.

Comment: Very true, AJAX is an option, in your experience is this the best way? Does MVC require a redirection always for an actionresult?

Comment: If you don't use ajax, your web browser will be expecting a new page to be sent...even if it's the exact same page you are currently on. If you use ajax, it's up to you what (if anything) you choose to return...and the default operation will be for the web browser to just stay on the current page (and not do anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after successful submit redirect to edit View

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit","ControllerName", new { id = match.MatchID });
```

and if there is some error in edit that do

```
return View();
```

and if you want to use ajax behaviour in form you can use

```
Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateEmail", "Ajax", new AjaxOptions...
```

you can see this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC) for details